# SSRS2017 Report rendering crashes Internet Explorere 11

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

Recently, we have upgraded SSRS2008R2 to SSRS2017. All the reports are working as expected except one report. There is a Report that produces ~250 columns(Matrix Control used) and whenever we try to run this report, IE11 is getting crashed or report keeps rendering.

Same report is working as expected in SSRS2008R2.

Any Thought to fix this issue in SSRS2017

Comment: does it work on other browsers? Edge for example? From memory, the reports render different from SSRS 2016 on wards.. HTML5 an all that..

Comment: We have chrome and IE11 and both the browser has same issue.